# How to get some elements in nested JSON objects in a JSON array

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I hava this JSON:

```
[
  {

    "title": "This a Sample title for each post_title",

    "excerpt": "And this is a sample of the post_body,

    "author": "King Spark",

    "featured_picture": {

      "source": "https://exapmple.com/blah/blah/image.jpg",
      "year": "2015",
      "ownwer": "Akim Man",

    },

  },...
```

From the json I only need the **title**, **excerpt** elements of the main objects. Then from the **featured_picture** objects, I want only the **source** element.

I have written this code and it seems not to be working:

```
private void parseData(JSONArray array){
        Log.d(TAG, "Parsing array");

        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
            PostItems postItem = new PostItems();
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            try {
                jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                postItem.setPost_title(jsonObject.getString(ConfigPost.TAG_POST_TITLE));
                postItem.setPost_body(jsonObject.getString(ConfigPost.TAG_POST_BODY));

                //Parsing featured_pocture object


                for (int f = 0; f<array.length(); f++) {
                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(f);
                    JSONObject postImage = object.getJSONObject("featured_picture");
                    String imageURL = postImage.getString("source");
                    postItem.setPost_image(imageURL);
                }





            } catch (JSONException w) {
                w.printStackTrace();
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Error in parsing Json", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            mPostItemsList.add(postItem);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to parse the nested JSON like this way:

```
   private void parseData(JSONArray array){
    Log.d(TAG, "Parsing array");

    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
        PostItems postItem = new PostItems();
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        try {
            jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);

   postItem.setPost_title(jsonObject.getString(ConfigPost.TAG_POST_TITLE));

   postItem.setPost_body(jsonObject.getString(ConfigPost.TAG_POST_BODY));

    //Parsing featured_picture object
   JSONObject postImage = jsonObject.getJSONObject("featured_picture");

   postItem.setPost_image(postImage.getString("source"));


        } catch (JSONException w) {
            w.printStackTrace();
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Error in parsing Json", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        mPostItemsList.add(postItem);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't continue read the array here

```
for (int f = 0; f<array.length(); f++) {
```

`featured_picture` is an entry in the map and returns a map too.

The acces should be like this :

```
array.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("featured_picture").getString("source");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to identify object and array in json then find value by key, once you learnt then complexity of  json doesn't matter to parse [follow tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm)

Answer (score 0):

your code `for (int f = 0; f<array.length(); f++) {
                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(f);
                    JSONObject postImage = object.getJSONObject("featured_picture");
                    String imageURL = postImage.getString("source");
                    postItem.setPost_image(imageURL);
                }`
is not correct, this part of json is not an array but an object inside another jsonObject.

Answer (score 0):

Here no need to iterate loop to read nested `JSONobject`.

Because "featured_picture" gives only `JSONObject` not an array. In case if its return array you should read like this:

```
JSONObject rootObject=new JSONObject();
JSONArray nestedObject=rootObject.getJSONArray("key");
```

Here i modified your code in correct manner hope will it help for you.

```
 for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
            PostItems postItem = new PostItems();
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            try {
                jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                   postItem.setPost_title(jsonObject.getString(ConfigPost.TAG_POST_TITLE));
                postItem.setPost_body(jsonObject.getString(ConfigPost.TAG_POST_BODY));

                //Parsing featured_pocture object

 JSONObject postImage = jsonObject.getJSONObject("featured_picture");
   String imageURL = postImage.getString("source");
         postItem.setPost_image(imageURL);


            } catch (JSONException w) {
                w.printStackTrace();
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Error in parsing Json", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```